# SetWindowsHookEx ignoring PostMessage from message loop

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I am trying to mod an older game, more specifically I want to emulate keyboard input via Xbox controller input. I already have the gamepad input working, but the game ignores my fake input I create with [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) (I tried PostThreadMessage as well with worse outcome.)

So here is the core piece of my code, a detour of [PeekMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx) :

```
BOOL WINAPI MyPeekMessage(LPMSG lpMsg, HWND hWnd, UINT wMsgFilterMin, UINT wMsgFilterMax, UINT wRemoveMsg)
{
    BOOL ret = RealPeekMessage(lpMsg, hWnd, wMsgFilterMin, wMsgFilterMax, wRemoveMsg);
    if (lpMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        cout << "Key press";
    }

    if (!ret)
    {
        if (joypadButtonDown)
        {
            LPARAM lparam = 0x00000001 | (LPARAM)(EnterScanCode << 16);    // Scan code, repeat=1
            BOOL res = PostMessage(mainHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, lparam);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Now the problem is that the game doesn't use its message loop to read keyboard input, but instead uses SetWindowsHookEx with WH_KEYBOARD on its own main window thread.
So on a real key press what happens is :
 The game's main loop calls my detour which calls the real PeekMessage which calls the hook procedure. But if I send my fake message (with identical parameters) the game again calls my detour but the real PeekMessage doesn't call the hook procedure and therefore misses the input.

Some additional Info :
 - I've checked that everything happens on the same thread (Main window creation, setting the hook and the main loop)
 - I tried sending PostMessage directly from IDirectInputDevice8->GetDeviceState with the same result
 - Invoking the hook procedure directly causes a crash (which makes sense).

Comment: Feel like back to medieval

Comment: Posting fake keyboard input does not trigger hooks. Only true keyboard input triggers hooks. Consider SendInput.

Comment: 1) Check `res` for sucess code. 2) Why (when) are you even being called by the app? Seems like an endless loop (you post message and your hook intercepts it)

Comment: @RaymondChen SendInput does indeed work but obviously only when the game window has focus, which is undesirable in my case. Also do you have a source that only "true" keyboard input triggers hooks? Because [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984(v=vs.85).aspx) says " The system calls this function whenever an application calls the GetMessage or PeekMessage function and there is a keyboard message (WM_KEYUP or WM_KEYDOWN) to be processed." which should be true for my fake input.

Comment: @krOoze 1) PostMessage succeeds. 2) I override PeekMessage which the game calls in its main message loop and I insert my fake input once the msg queue is empty so it gets processed in the next "frame".

Comment: The text assumes that you're not crazy enough to be posting fake input (because that already doesn't work for other reasons; for example, `GetKeyState` is not updated when you post fake keyboard input). If you want to be precise, it would say "There is a keyboard message in the input queue". Manually posted messages do not go into the input queue; they go into the posted message queue.

Comment: @DeadlySurprise ad 2) That's ambiguous. So you inject DLL to the game with `SetWindowsHookEx` and WH_GETMESSAGE?

Also: You can't be sure the queue is empty ATM, can you? Anyway, why defer input to the next frame. And why wait for empty queue?

You should `CallNextHookEx()` to be safe. And you should set repeat(bit 30) on multiple WM_KEYDOWN and also WM_KEYUP should be somewhere there.

Comment: @RaymondChen I did try to post fake input. The game doesn't use GetKeyState, it just uses its own keyboard hook for what ever reason. And regular input is posted as well, I've checked with Spy++. My fake input was exactly the same as real input so still no clue why postmessage didn't work.

Comment: @krOoze I don't use `SetWindowsHookEx` to hook the game, I use `CreateRemoteThread` and Microsoft Detours. The game **itself** uses `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_Keyboard` to hook its own message queue. And the problem was that `PeekMessage` didn't invoke the game's hook procedure when processing my fake posted messages.

Comment: Posted messages arrive via the posted message queue; regular input arrives via the input queue. Spy++ doesn't tell you which queue a message came from. Both posted messages and input messages are reported by PostMessage (so Spy++ reports it as such). The reason it doesn't work is that WH_KEYBOARD is raised only for input messages that come from the input queue. Not fake messages that come from the posted message queue.

Comment: @RaymondChen source? The MSDN says whenever there is WM_KEYDOWN in Peek/GetMessage.

Comment: I will have the documentation clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a somewhat dirty workaround. I call the game's SetWindowsHookEx KeyboardProc callback directly and avoid the crash I mentioned in the OP by detouring CallNextHookEx to ignore my fake hook calls.